# 'Automation error Library not registered' when running Excel 2016 VBA with Project 2010

Tags: vba, excel, registry, ms-project

I have just tried everything but nothing work.

This is the start of my code:

```
 Public Sub Connect()

    Dim appProj As MSProject.Application
    Dim Resp As Variant

       Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
       Set Cronograma = appProj.ActiveProject

       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project")
          If UCase(Trim(Cronograma.name)) = UCase(Trim(.Cells(4, 2))) Then
             Resp = MsgBox("Plan OK" & vbNewLine & "Starting line: " & Cronograma.Tasks.Count + 1 & vbNewLine _
                             & "Continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Generator")
             If Resp = vbYes Then
                Status 1
                Call Main
             End If
          Else
             'Nothing
          End If
       End With

 End Sub
```

It's enough to get it working properly with Excel 2013 and lower, but since I had to change to Excel 2016 (Office365) this error started to show every time I use project objects, in this case when I try to count tasks:

> Run-time error '-2147319779 (8002801d)':
>
> Automation error Library not registered.

I've already tried everything that I found on the internet like registry cleaning of old Keys, unregistering and registering libraries, late binding the project object and much more.

Does anyone have yet discovered a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while but i finally managed to find a workaround for this.

As i said on the main post, the late binding wasnt working, but after some tests i just had to late bing all the other objects on the code and force the association with the right environment

Like this:

```
Dim appProj As Object
Dim Resp As Variant

   Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application.10")
   Set Cronograma = appProj.ActiveProject
```